# MVC2 Noobie Question - How to Ajax post data to a controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a really simple request, but I'm stuck on how to implement the ajax stuff.

Basically on document.ready, I've got a javascript method that checks for a "UTCOffset" cookie, and if it doesn't exist, it will do a "behinds the scenes" ajax post to a controller that sets the offset.

Basically I'm trying to make it so that the user doesn't have to manually input their UTC offset.

How would I implement the Ajax post to the Action?  Is the action supposed to be a "Sub" instead of a "Function" (since functions are supposed to return something.

Comment: page load? you mean document.ready? this is not web forms (thankfully). :)

Comment: yes yes, i mean document.ready... bad habit.. lol

Comment: hahah, old habits die hard. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)** (or regular **[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**).

```
$.post("home/save", data, function (data) {
   // handle result, or ignore it if you don't care.
});
```

Your action method might look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(int someId)
{
   // do the foo

   var result = new { code: 0 }; // or code : 1 if error occured (for example)
   return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: nps. and also, you should at least return **something** from the action, at least a success/error code. Also if your posting a ViewModel, make sure the action method can accept it. But it sounds like your just posting a primitive value.